# truncate characters of text within a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a bit of an issue here.

I'm basically looping items in a div so that each one has a key that can be used so that when an icon is clicked, an edit modal appears and populates with the selected Item's data.

This works, but I want to add functionality for my span `<span>{{ $node->comment }}</span>` so that if the text is more than 10 characters, it replaces everything after 10 characters with '***'. I've attempted this by adding `element.innerHTML = getValue.substring(0 ,4) + ' *** '` but it doesn't work and it oberrides the functionality of using a key.

Is there a way to replace the text characters and keep the loop/key functionality?

```
@foreach($nodes as $key => $node)  


        <div class="uk-width-1-1">
            <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                {{$node->id}} - {{$node->desc}}
                </div>
                <div class="uk-width-2-10 testLoop">
                    <span>{{ $node->comment }}</span> 
                     <a href="#edit-modal{{ $key }}" data-uk-modal><span class="uk-icon-check"></span></a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="edit-modal{{ $key }}" class="uk-modal"> 
            <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
                <div class="uk-width-1-1">
                    <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                        <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                        {{$node->id}} - {{$node->desc}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="uk-width-2-10 testLoop">
                            <span>{{ $node->comment }}</span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
@endforeach

function testLoop() {

var comment = document.getElementsByClassName('testLoop'),
    commentText = comment;

for (var index = 0; index < commentText.length; index++) {
    var element = commentText[index];
    var getValue = element.children[0].innerHTML;

    element.addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log('click');
    })      
    }       
}
testLoop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substring should be `(0,10)` for ten characters.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('text')
element.innerText = element.innerText.substring(0,10) + '***'
```

```html
<span id='text'>Long long long long text</span>
```

**Another Approach**

Instead of character length, use `max-width`, and set your `CSS` to truncate and show an ellipsis.  The CSS does all the work for you.

```css
#text {
  max-width: 90px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id='text'>This is a long, long, long string.</div>
```

Comment: I like the CSS version much better, using it now. Thanks!

Comment: There is a version of text-overflow that lets you specify the characters, but it does not work on Chrome.